# Selenium Webdriver - Element not clickable error

Tags: selenium

One of test case is randomly failing in chrome driver

I am checking wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ele));
I have also tried thread. sleep

I get following error..Thanks..

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not
>   clickable at point (547, 498). Other element would receive the click:
>   ...   (Session info:
>   chrome=43.0.2357.134)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322455
>   (ae8db840dac8d0c453355d3d922c91adfb61df8f),platform=Mac OS X 10.9.5
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 56 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:58'
>   System info: host: 'Maitris-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '10.9.20.70',
>   os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.5',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_71' Session ID: dba4c84dc3f18442e47aeae5d05e5655
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=MAC, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   browserName=chrome,
>   chrome={userDataDir=/var/folders/c6/sn_7hhjj7mqdjp12gk50p4kw0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.2Ug99c},
>   rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=43.0.2357.134,
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false,
>   takesScreenshot=true}]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:50)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.click(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.baublebar.pages.BaublebarPage.addBundleProduct(BaublebarPage.java:493)
>     at
>   com.baublebar.testcases.shoppingcart.AddBundleProductTest.addBundleTest(AddBundleProductTest.java:28)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)   at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)     at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)  at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your element changed its locator, or the 'real' element has a different locator.
Just some questions:
- Did you check for the element presence at the time this error showed up? Is it the same locator?
- Isn't it some fade that is causing the error?
- What kind of element are you trying to click, a normal button?

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are two elements I have issue with..button and label...If I add thread.sleep that works.....I don't see anything on that page..

Answer (score 0):

> Element is not clickable at point (547, 498). Other element would receive the click:

Means that there is something 'on top of' the element you are trying to click.

You need to figure out what it is and wait for it to go away, or add some conditional code to make it go away.

The problem we had was a "do you accept our cookies" dialog that was scrolling into the page. On big developer monitors it never covered anything, but on the smaller screens on our selenium test clients it was covering up some buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I add thread.sleep that works.....I don't see anything on that page..